# Get value of custom attribute for user in Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, .net-4.6

I am trying to read the values of a few custom attributes that have been added inside Active Directory but I can't find anything that explains how to do this. I have found a page that helped me make the connection and find the user and this allows me to read some of the pre-made attributes but it did not cover how to read custom attributes. Searching on Google/SO all I find are outdated instrutions that use `DirectoryEntry` which appears to have been dropped in the later .Net released. I say this since Visual Studio has no idea what that object is or what namespace it belongs to.

Can anyone tell me how I am supposed to read custom attributes?

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JobSight.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
            UpdateUserFromAD();
        }

        private void UpdateUserFromAD()
        {
                var Context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainController");
                var UserData = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any evidence that support for DirectoryEntry is being dropped.

UserPrincipal is really just a wrapper for DirectoryEntry, as implied in the documentation for the [GetUnderlyingObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.getunderlyingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

You'll be able to use the Properties from DirectoryEntry to get any attribute in AD.

Comment: When I do a simple `var test = new DirectoryEntry()` Visual Studio does gves me the error "The Type of Namespace 'DirectoryEntry' does not exist, are you missing a reference" but when I ask it for a suggetssed using it does not have any. If I add `using System.DirectoryServices` like all the old/outdated examples say to do get the same error trying to call into 'DirectoryEntry'. If it has not been dropped then what namespace does it live in? And if `UserPrincipal` is just a rapper should it not expose the `Properties` method so I can search for my custom attribute?

Comment: Adding a "using" statement is not enough. You have to add the reference in the project too. In Solution Explorer, under your project, right-click on 'References' and click 'Add'. Find 'System.DirectoryServices' in the window that comes up and add it.